# How can I avoid 2 loops and have my data stored in array in Perl

Tags: loops, perl

I have a script, which does count number of data in the input `DATA` and based on the count it will further proceed.

Below is my script, which is working as expected.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my (@array, @nodes);

my $count = 0;
while (<DATA>) {
    push @array, $_;
    $count = $1 if /Total number of data found :\s*(\d+)/;
}
print "Count:$count\n";

print "Array".Dumper(\@array);

if( $count > 0 ){
    foreach my $ele(@array){
        chomp $ele;
        if( $ele =~ /NodeName : (\w+)/){
            push @nodes, $1;
        }
    }
} else {
    print "Count is less than 1.. Existing\n";
    exit 0;
}

print Dumper(\@nodes);

__DATA__
Data : Network=R9,N=Node1
NodeName : Node1
DateTime : 05-08-2020 10:00:05

Data : Network=R9,N=Node2
NodeName : Node2
DateTime : 05-08-2020 10:00:10

Total number of data found : 2
```

But here I am using 2 loops, `while` and `foreach`.

`while` is used to capture the count and `foreach` is to iterate through each data elements which is been stored in `@array` while doing `while` operation.

Is it possible to have only 1 loop, either `while` or `for` where I can get the count and based on the count I can get the `NodeName` from the `DATA`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my @nodes;

my $count = 0;
while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;

  push @nodes, $1 if /NodeName : (\w+)/;
  $count = $1 if /Total number of data found :\s*(\d+)/;
}
print "Count:$count\n";

if ($count <= 0) {
    print "Count is less than 1.. Exiting\n";
    exit 0;
}

print Dumper(\@nodes);

__DATA__
Data : Network=R9,N=Node1
NodeName : Node1
DateTime : 05-08-2020 10:00:05

Data : Network=R9,N=Node2
NodeName : Node2
DateTime : 05-08-2020 10:00:10

Total number of data found : 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Above solution is good. But if your data is in file (file operation) you can use https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Grep module

> fmap BLOCK LIST

Performs a map operation on the files in LIST, using BLOCK as the mapping function. The results from BLOCK will be appended to the list that is returned at the end of the call.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Grep qw(fmap);
use Data::Dumper;

my @nodes;
my $count_flag = 0;

# my @result  = fmap { <block> } file_name; 
# modified "Total number .." regex, added \s*[1-9]\d*$ 
# (checking number between 1-9 followed by \d equivalent to [0-9])
# so if Total number of data found value is greater than zero setting flag to 1
fmap { (/NodeName : (\w+)/ ? push(@nodes,$1) : ((/Total number of data found :\s*[1-9]\d*$/) ? $count_flag = 1 : () ) )} *DATA;

if ($count_flag) {
    print Dumper(\@nodes);
} else {
    print "Count is less than 1.. Exiting\n";
    exit 0;
}

__DATA__
Data : Network=R9,N=Node1
NodeName : Node1
DateTime : 05-08-2020 10:00:05

Data : Network=R9,N=Node2
NodeName : Node2
DateTime : 05-08-2020 10:00:10

Total number of data found : 1
```

> Output

```
$VAR1 = [
          'Node1',
          'Node2'
        ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Push elements to `@nodes` array in the first loop.
Use `@nodes` array after the loop only if `$count` is right.

You may clear `@nodes` array using `@nodes = () ;`.